# Eclipse doxygen style when using /*!

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, doxygen

I am using eclipse photon 4.8 on Ubuntu 18.04. When I start a doxygen comment block with /*! and hit Enter, eclipse is unable to change the general style of parameters like `@brief`, `@param` or `@return` to another scheme like `\brief`, `\param` or `\return`.

I am unable to find any switch which can make this change. If we talk about the schemes specifically, this is the change from the JavaDoc style to Qt-style (C/C++).

Comment: Why do you want to change from `@` to `\\` style? doxygen accepts both.

Comment: I know Doxygen accepts both, depending on the project (also preference) this style can be different. And, for the sake of consistency at the moment, I was looking for \.

Comment: consistency is a great thing.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm through a quick look at the CDT source code that no such option is supported, the `@param` style is hard-coded.

[Patches are welcome](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development)!

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Unfortunately, at the moment I don't have to work on it. So, I hope meanwhile someone works on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the style starting from Eclipse 2020-03 [source](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn911).
You can customize the options in 
C/C++->Editor in documentation tool section.

Comment: How, where? some more explanation might be useful.

Comment: see cdt news and noteworthy web page for Cdt 9.11

Comment: Please make at  least a reference to this, but more important place the relevant information in the answer, people don't like to jump to other places and the answer should contain this kind of information (small hints to what to do / find the possibility in the menu bar etc.).